# How to check if a page hosted in a Web Browser Control is already rendered?

Tags: wpf, browser, render

Hy People!. I'm here again asking for your help. I have a web browser control in a Wpf App. Into the event Load of the mainwindows I set up the control's source:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
             webBrowser1.Source = new Uri(ConnectionString);
             webBrowser1.Navigate(ConnectionString);
    }
```

I'm redirected to the following url: https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3acrm%3adynamics.com&wctx=rm%3d1%26id%3de513a320-df72-4de8-bce8-b1f918dc4eff%26ru%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fwebfortis38.crm.dynamics.com%252fdefault.aspx&wct=2011-09-06T14%3a49%3a38Z

At this point I must Sign in with my Windows Live Id. To do that I look for the Input controls in order to fill them up with my username and my Pass, and then the button submit in order to calls the event Click():

```
            HTMLDocument mdoc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document;
            IHTMLElement usern = mdoc.getElementById("i0116"); 
            IHTMLElement dom = mdoc.getElementById("i0118");
            IHTMLElement btl = mdoc.getElementById("idSIButton9");

            if (usern != null && dom != null && btl != null)
            {
                // pass authentication
                usern.setAttribute("value", UserName);
                dom.setAttribute("value", password);

                btl.click();
                IsRendered=true;
            }
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM!. If the page is not already rendered, the procedure getElementById returns Null!!.

Is there any way to know when the page is completely rendered?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

1. Start a new thread from DocumentCompleted,
2. from the new thread's entry point,
3. sleep for 500ms, (or however long is safe to allow complete JavaScript initialization)
4. invoke to the webbrowser's owning thread,
5. now work with the computed document

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigated event of webBrowser1.

Comment: Hy and thanks for your help. But sadly this event is fired before the page is completely rendered.

Comment: You are right, i checked my code again and i use documentcompleted event.

Comment: I tryed, but: can documentcompleted be used in wpf projects?. I think that it only can be used  in Windows Forms Projects.

Comment: Hy and thanks for your help. But sadly this event is fired before the page is completely rendered. The GetElementbyId functions still responsing a null object

Comment: I found a way. I had to use a new thread where I check with a DO-WHILE for the elements that I'm interested in (using GetElementById).

Answer (score 0):

Hy, a could solve the problem. What I've done is to create a new thread. Into this new thread I've inserted my code into a DO-WHILE loop and with a thread.abort() into the IF loop. Thanks for the help